# Expose 'Internal Status' in List

Tags: sharepoint-online, nintex

Is it possible to expose the 'Internal Status' of a workflow into the associated List? I want to be able to look at all my List items and determine whether the workflow has been started, completed, suspended or terminated.

Thanks,
Andrew

Answer (score 0):

When you attach workflow to list (custom using SharePoint Designer or default out of box workflow from list settings), the column with workflow name is automatically addedd to default view.

However if that wasn't happened, edit the view you're using in your list and add a column with your workflow name to it.

You can use this column to check the status whether it is started,completed or suspended.

Comment: Is this for SharePoint O365 or on prem? For SharePoint O365, it doesn't seem to be working.

Comment: It does work for sp online as well. Check on the Modify view if you are able to see this column.

Answer (score 0):

When you start a workflow in the list, there will be a column about the workflow status automatically generated.

[image]

Or you could click Workflows in the tab to see workflow status.

Comment: Is this for SharePoint O365 or on prem? For SharePoint O365, it doesn't seem to be working.

Comment: Per my test, in the SharePoint Online, it does work.